# How to display a user language dialog from menus in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, dialog, menuitem

I want to open dialogs in WPF (Save, Open, Print…) with the user language.

How do I find the user language?
How do I open the dialogs with that language?

The menus and sub-menus are shown automatically in the correct language.

```
e.g. Command = Application.save
```

A sample code will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Find the one that looks like it would be right for you and your project's requirements. I will offer one solution that I use.

> *How do I find the user language?*

A machine can have different cultures and each thread can even have its own culture. A culture contains both display language and date/number formatting info, etc.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

For the purpose of this answer, you shouldn't need to access these objects directly.

> *How do I open the dialogs with that language?*

I localize my projects with the resource file (RESX) method.
Start off by creating Resource files for the cultures you want to support plus a default, like so.

*Resources.resx*
*Resources.en.resx*
*Resources.fr.resx*
*Resoucess.ja.resx*

If you want to be **specific** use the full culture code.
*Resources.ja-JP*

Now add all your localized text to the resources, the default as well.

The default will be used when the display language is not of your supported language set.

The WPF app will select the display culture of the windows user to choose which RESX file to use.
Bind to the RESX files in your XAML.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.Owner}"/>  
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.StartDate}" />  
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.EndDate}"/>
```

Here I have three text blocks that statically bind to the Resources.Owner StartDate and EndDate properties. The properties keyword is not specifying that you will use a property but the Resources object in the properties group of your application.

If you have trouble with the static binding, check that your namespaces are correct. 
Note that you shouldn't reference directly to any of the specific resources. The ResourceManager will handle the loading of the correct file.
If you need dynamic language switching, please view some of the good Resource Globalization tutorials available on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Syntax to get the User language in WPF...

```
XmlLanguage language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```

I hope this will help you..